# How to close only one connection in SCTP one-to-many style c programming

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking, sctp

C programming
I have been able to create One-To-many style of SCTP connection, using

```
clientsockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

Able to send connect and send message to multiple servers using same single socket(binded to single local ip and port)

while sending message I am using destination ip:port in each message,

```
int res = sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, message, strlen(message), (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr1, sizeof(server_addr1), 0, SCTP_ADDR_OVER, 0, 0, 0);
```

Now I want to close only one connection out of these two, I checked the sctp manual/api reference doc.
It suggests to use, SCTP_EOF or SCTP_ABORT flag with specific connection/association id, I tried many combinations, but it caused both connections to ABORT.
Any suggestions?

```
    sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, NULL, 0,NULL, 0, 0, SCTP_ABORT,asso_id,0,0);
```

and

```
sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, NULL, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr1, 0, 0, SCTP_ABORT,(uint16_t)sp.spinfo_assoc_id,0,0);
```

I read this message being deprecated.

gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SCTP, but I'm pretty sure you need to send the ABORT or EOF message (EOF for normal termination) to the client you want disconnect, *identified by address*.  In that regard, note that the 8th parameter to `sctp_sendmsg()` is a *stream* number, not an *association* number.  Each association can have multiple streams in each direction, and as far as I can determine, stream numbers are not unique to an association.

Comment: It's hard to give any specifics, though, because the code presented in the question is so fragmentary.

Comment: Thanks for yout comment, Yes, an SCTP association/connection can have 65,535 stream to allow parallel data transfer between two endpoints, I am looking to close a single association in One-to-many style of SCTP connection.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and my first comment addresses how I think you should be doing it.  The code fragments presented in the question do not appear to match that.  Additionally, those fragments give the impression that you misunderstand the nature of the stream number parameter, but if that impression is incorrect then so much the better.

Comment: Yes,I still need to find, how to close a single association in one-to-many time of SCTP connection, where one client socket can be used to connect to Mutiple server,that mean one client socket may be used for 10 SCTP association, I cannot used close(clientfd), it will close all the association.
the API doc says
Use send_msg and pass "SCTP_EOF/SCTP_ABORT" along with association_id but function parameter has stream_id.
       SCTP_EOF
              Setting this flag invokes the SCTP graceful shutdown
              procedure on the specific association(one-to-many style
              only).

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was, I was not passing length of server_addr1, as 5th parameter in sctp_send() call

```
sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, NULL, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr1, 0, 0, SCTP_ABORT,(uint16_t)sp.spinfo_assoc_id,0,0);
```

Working api call

```
sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, NULL, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr1,sizeof(server_addr1) , 0, SCTP_ABORT,(uint16_t)sp.spinfo_assoc_id,0,0);
```

And

```
sctp_sendmsg(clientsockfd, NULL, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr1,sizeof(server_addr1) , 0, SCTP_EOF,(uint16_t)sp.spinfo_assoc_id,0,0);
```